# .htaccess to remove .html causing redirect loop

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file is creating a redirect loop. I have searched online and tried lots of varieties including many from this site but still can't get it to work. The purpose of it is to remove the .html from the end of the URL.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.+?)\.html?[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NE,R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

## append trailing slash if needed

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You need to know (from hosting provider) where Apache error log is. It is important for your future work as well. Meanwhile try commenting `Options` line at top.

Comment: I have done that and now the site loads. It has fixed the redirect loop but when I navigate around another slash is added each time before the page.

Comment: Do you have `RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]` OR `RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

Comment: If you notice in my answer I have `RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]` now :P

Comment: OK I have changed it and it works but 2 of my pages which have spaces in are giving 404 errors.

Comment: What are those URLs with spaces?

Comment: Find Us and Contact Us

Comment: And you have `Find Us.html` file?

Comment: Yes and so I could just remove the space and update my links but I would prefer not to.

Comment: Ok that goes well beyond the stated problem on this question :). Anyway check the edited answer now.